# How to replicate the effect of 'end=''' in the print function into a variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have some code that turns a list of intergers into the characters they represent in ascii This all works fine but it prints every character in a new line. I fixed this by adding 'end=''' to the print statement. However, I want this output (a one line string) inside a variable so I can do different things with it. How do I do this?

This is the code with the working print statement:

```
a = [116, 101, 115, 116, 115, 116, 114, 105, 110, 103]

for x in range(len(a)):
    data = (chr(a[x]))
    print(data, end='')
```

I already tried things like rsplit and join but nothing gives the correct outcome.

Thank you for any help you can give me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible with a `join` and list comprehension:

```
data = ''.join([chr(a[x]) for x in range(len(a))])
```

Note that you definitely did not want to iterate over the indices but the elements themselves, so a better approach would come from a foreach loop:

```
data = ''.join([chr(x) for x in a])
```

A functional approach seems not bad too:

```
data = ''.join(map(chr, a))
```

---

Post that you simply have to:

```
print(data)
```

Comment: Or even `join` with a generator expression - `data = ''.join(chr(x) for x in a)`.

Comment: @wwii, that is not as efficient as list comp.

Comment: .. 5% slower for 100 million ... If time efficiency is the goal you should point out that `map` is the fastest.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [116, 101, 115, 116, 115, 116, 114, 105, 110, 103]

# empty string
result = ""
# loops trough the list
for x in a:
    # the converted character is added to the string
    result + = chr(x)
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, including an explanation of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to ADD EXPLANATION and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
import sys

a = [116, 101, 115, 116, 115, 116, 114, 105, 110, 103]

for x in range(len(a)):
    data = (chr(a[x]))
    sys.stdout.write(data)
```

Output :

```
teststring
```